# "Unable to find remote helper for 'https'" during git clone

Tags: linux, git, ubuntu

I am unable to clone HTTPS repositories. I can clone SSH repos fine, but not HTTPS repos. I cannot test the GIT protocol since I am behind a corporate firewall.

This is what I am trying to do:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/nvie/gitflow.git
Cloning into gitflow...
fatal: Unable to find remote helper for 'https'
```

I have so far tried the following (based on Google searches)

- Purging and installing Git through `apt-get`
- Installing `build-deps` for Git through `apt-get`
- Installing curl dev libraries
- Installing expat libraries
- Downloading Git source and building using:

  - `./configure --prefix=/usr --with-curl --with-expat`
  - Also tried pointing configure at curl binary (`./configure --prefix=/usr --with-curl=/usr/bin/curl`)

I have tried everything I can find on the internet with no luck. Can anyone help me?

Git version = 1.7.6.4

OS = Ubuntu 11.04

Comment: Sorry to be obvious, it sounds like curl isn't installed.  do `curl --help` and see if it is.

Comment: I am getting back a list of curl options when I run curl --help.

Comment: I know, like I mentioned at the top of my question, I've gone through every result I can find in Google. Nothing has worked so far!

Comment: Nothing appears in syslog after I run the git clone command, sadly.

Comment: I have the same issue. I'm behind a corporate firewall too.
I tried to recompile with all the options found in Internet, but not work at all. Any other idea?

Comment: I have tried everything suggested in the answers, plus a whole lot more. Since there does not seem to be a solution I am closing the question. In the end I have re-installed my PC and the problem did not re-occur.

Comment: You got the same issue when you have the wrong curl PROXY setup.

Comment: Funny thing is, I'm trying to clone from curl's github so that I can compile it on a locked-down $&#%^* Solaris box.

Comment: One more suggestion to anybody struggling with this, make sure you check your `GIT_EXEC_PATH` environment variable to make sure it isn't pointing somewhere silly.

Comment: I had this error message because i made a typo and had "ssh:://" (notice the double : <-)

Comment: Maybe it'll work with ssh?

Answer (score 320, accepted):

It looks like not having (lib)curl-devel installed when you compile git can cause this.

If you install (lib)curl-devel, and then rebuild/install git, this should solve the problem:

```
$ yum install curl-devel
$ # cd to wherever the source for git is
$ cd /usr/local/src/git-1.7.9  
$ ./configure
$ make
$ make install
```

This worked for me on Centos 6.3.

If you don't have yum, you can download the source to curl-devel here:

- http://curl.se/dlwiz/?type=devel

---

If you are running Ubuntu instead:

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev
```

Comment: these steps worked for me. CentOS 5.8 32 bit ;git version 1.8.0

Comment: Also for me, red hat linux 5.

Comment: Worked for me CentOS 6.4 and git 1.8.2.1

Comment: Which linux package to get for CentOS? the RedHat one?

Comment: On Ubuntu 12.04 LTS the package I needed was: `sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev`

Comment: On Ubuntu 10.04 LTS the package I needed was: `sudo aptitude install libcurl4-openssl-dev`
apt-get has dependency problem and aptitude seems can resolve it

Comment: I had this problem because I was working on git itself, and had done a "make install" into my ~/bin directory.  My PATH picked up ~/bin/git which encountered the error.  Using /usr/bin/git solved the problem.

Comment: Worked for me on CentOS 6.6. Thanks

Comment: Note that it seems libcurl-devel needs to be installed on the machine you're running the binary from.  I compiled git from a machine with libcurl-devel and it works, but when I move the binary to a machine without libcurl-devel it doesn't work.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for Ubuntu VM on Azure. I've been at this for an entire day. I keep getting the 'https' error.

Comment: Great answer! On CentOS 7, I also run `yum` to install other libraries: `yum -y install gettext-devel openssl-devel curl-devel perl-CPAN perl-devel zlib-devel`

Comment: centos 6.9 el6-i386. Worked like a charm

Comment: Nothing worked for me, even after 4 hours of trying different solutions. At the end, I downloaded and installed an older version of git. I am now using 1.9.5, I had to uninstall 2.9.1

Comment: Would like to understand, what exactly is the difference with curl-devel over curl that makes this work?  From behind the firewall I can set proxies such that curl can successfully fetch that Git project URL, so what are the default option differences and how to ask Git to use them.

Comment: Can you guide me the package for the MAC ?

Comment: I had to also restart shell in Debian. Since Git produced the same error in the old shell.

Comment: This worked for me on CentOS7 and git 2.9.5

Answer (score 90):

If you are trying to clone then you could use the git transport

For example: `git clone git://github.com/fog/fog.git`

```
Vaio ~/Myworks/Hero $ git clone git://github.com/fog/fog.git

Initialized empty Git repository in /home/nthillaiarasu/Myworks/Hero/fog/.git/
remote: Counting objects: 41138, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (13176/13176), done.
remote: Total 41138 (delta 27218), reused 40493 (delta 26708)
Receiving objects: 100% (41138/41138), 5.22 MiB | 58 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (27218/27218), done
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Unfortunately I work behind a corporate firewall that blocks the git protocol's port and they won't open it up for me. I've been downloading tarballs to bypass the issue, but I would really like to get my install of git working properly!

Comment: As others have mentioned, git:// isn't usually ideal, but apparently if you are in a situation in which https:// simply won't work, you can use `git config --global url."git://".insteadof https://` to force `git` to always use git:// instead of https://. This can be useful if you are trying to clone with submodules (e.g. with `--recursive`).

Comment: Perfect. I couldn't install anything on my QNAP cloud but this worked like a charm!

Comment: As of 2022, it seems that `git clone git://github.com/something` is not supported any more, resulting in a "remote error": "The unauthenticated git protocol on port 9418 is no longer supported."

Answer (score 71):

Just in case someone encounters this on a QNAP system or any other system with OPKG as package manager:

You need to install git-http along with git. Like:

```
opkg install git-http
```

Comment: You saved my day! This is exactly my case. I'm using "entware" on a Xpeonology system to get more Linux software packages, and after "opkg install git", the "git clone https://" will fail with error: fatal: Unable to find remote helper for 'https'. Thank you for mentioning this "git-http" package.

Comment: Thanks I understood the problem, but didn't know what the package was that would allow git to grab http data instead of ssh data.

Comment: unfortunately for me this didn't work. but using git:// instead of https:// as given in another answer did work for me

Comment: You saved my life as well! I'm using Synology DSM (DSM 7.0-41222 beta) and OPKG/Entware — I had absolutely no idea _why_ this didn't work straight out of the box, as it did in the past. The answer is simple: 'in the past' I was using the _official_ `git` that came with the box; a lot has been dropped during the beta, so I'm installing what I'm missing with OPKG/Entware... and thus the `git` version I'm now using is the one coming from there... which lacked HTTP support. Duh! Oh well. Thanks for pointing this out, I'd never figure it out by myself... the OPKG managers ought to put a warning!

Answer (score 51):

I used "`git://`" instead of "`https://`" and that solved the problem. My final command was:

```
git clone --recursive git://github.com/ceph/ceph.git
```

Comment: This is a workaround, not a solution. It will work for repos but not for gists, and not for the OP due to his corporate firewall.

Comment: And it also means you cannot push anything

Comment: @cecheverria : github doesn’t accept  push over git.

Comment: @PatrickFisher But it *does* work in environments where you don't have the rights to install the curl-devel libraries and/or the sysadmin won't install them promptly.

Comment: And it did help me to get my jenkins build server to run nightly builds. Thanks

Answer (score 28):

In our case, the problem was fixed when we checked

```
git --exec-path
```

was pointing to a path that stopped to exist.
(It was pointing to the path where we've compiled git and not where we copied afterwards for anyone to access it)

We did a:

```
export GIT_EXEC_PATH=<path_of_/libexec/git-core/>
```

and solved.

Comment: Thanks. The 2nd solution works for me when git is installed in separate folder.

Answer (score 16):

I had same problem and simple to resolve it.

Just uninstall git and re-install it.

```
#apt-get remove --purge git-svn git-core
#rm /usr/local/bin/git
#apt-get install git-svn git-core
```

and everything works well.

Hope this help.

Comment: You should do apt-get remove --purge git

Comment: This worked for me ... uninstalling git as above, then getting the git tarball, building and installing it.

Answer (score 16):

On CentOS 5.x, installing curl-devel fixed the problem for me.

Comment: @RyanM: This worked for me.  I `yum install curl-devel` and then I `./configure`, `make`, and `make install` on my git code.  Then https:// worked for me.  This is on CentOS 5.8

Answer (score 13):

If this problem occurred while tying to use github via the github commandline utility, the problem is likely due to using the snap version of gh.

If you can clone with `git clone` and not get this error, then the problem is with the snap version of `gh`.

In the end, the github docs saved the day! 
https://github.com/cli/cli/blob/trunk/docs/install_linux.md

Here's the steps to save some time (debian/ubuntu/Raspberry PiOS):

```
curl -fsSL https://cli.github.com/packages/githubcli-archive-keyring.gpg | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/githubcli-archive-keyring.gpg
echo "deb [arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture) signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/githubcli-archive-keyring.gpg] https://cli.github.com/packages stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/github-cli.list > /dev/null
sudo apt update
sudo apt install gh
```

Comment: this is the underrated answer :D, there is an issue on the snap package repository

Comment: I also swapped from snap's gh to apt's gh and it worked for me. Seems `gh` was using a different git path

Comment: I used Deanna's advise and removed the snap gh and installed apt's gh and it worked

Answer (score 12):

I had the exact same issue and it boiled down to an unmet dependency, however, I tried the accepted answer's solution and it did not work.

What finally worked for me was installing all of the following (this is RedHat):

```
sudo yum install curl-devel expat-devel gettext-devel openssl-devel zlib-devel
```

Afterwards, I ran the other commands as specified and it worked:

```
./configure
make
sudo make prefix=/usr/local install
```

I pulled the list of dependencies directly from [Git's website](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Installing-Git). Apparently I should have started there :/

Answer (score 8):

The easiest way to fix this problem is to ensure that the `git-core` is added to the `path` for your current user

If you add the following to your bash profile file in `~/.bash_profile` this should normally resolve the issue

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/libexec/git-core
```

Comment: the only solution worked for me is yours.
For others you can also fix it using above or use below command instead:

/usr/bin/git pull origin master

Comment: Also, ensure that your git-core has been built with git-remote-https included.

Comment: Worked for me -- without needing access to `sudo`. Should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me in Centos 6.6 to install git 2.3.1:

1. I didn't have curl-devel installed (checking for curl_global_init in -lcurl... no). The key was to generate configure script
2. [add rpmforge](http://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories/RPMForge) for docboox2x
3. install packages

   ```
   yum install openssl-devel zlib-devel perl-ExtUtils-MakeMaker svn tcl perl-Locale-Msgfmt gettext asciidoc xmlto docbook2x
   ```
4. make symlink

   ```
   ln -s /usr/bin/db2x_docbook2texi /usr/bin/docbook2x-texi
   ```
5. build git

   ```
   # download latest relase from https://github.com/git/git/releases
   curl -O -J -L https://github.com/git/git/archive/v2.13.0.tar.gz
   tar xf git-2.13.0.tar.gz
   cd git-2.13.0
   make configure
   ./configure --prefix=/usr
   make all doc
   make install install-doc install-html
   ```

Comment: Wait a second... the problem is that git clone https:// fails.  How are you fixing it by cloning the the git source???  Anybody reading this question won't be able to do step 5.

Comment: added curl and tar usage

Answer (score 3):

On Mac OS X 10.9 Mavericks, the solution that worked is as follows

```
rvm pkg install openssl
CC=/usr/local/bin/gcc-4.2 CPP=/usr/local/bin/cpp-4.2 CXX=/usr/local/bin/g++-4.2  rvm install 1.9.3 --with-openssl-dir=$rvm_path/usr
```

This is to compile Ruby with OpenSSL Support. Next, uninstall all the old versions.

```
brew uninstall openssl
brew uninstall curl
brew uninstall git
```

Next, install the updated versions. The git installation is dependent on an updated version of CURL.

```
brew install openssl
brew install curl
brew install git
```

Comment: This worked for me ... had to remove `CC=/usr/local/bin/gcc-4.2 CPP=/usr/local/bin/cpp-4.2 CXX=/usr/local/bin/g++-4.2 ` though & used higher ruby version

Comment: On macOS 10.14 (Mojave) my simple solution was to use Anaconda I had already installed, and type `conda install git` to install a newer git version and dependency packages.

Answer (score 2):

I was having this issue when using capistrano to deploy a rails app. The problem was that my user only had a jailed shell access in cpanel. Changing it to normal shell access fixed my problem.

Comment: How can this be fixed while keeping the user jailed?  What needs to be added to `jk_init.ini` under `[git]` to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

For those using git with [Jenkins](https://jenkins.io/) under a windows system, you need to configure the location of *git.exe* under:
**Manage Jenkins** => **Global Tool Configuration** => **Git** => **Path to Git executable** and fill-in the path to *git.exe*, for example; *C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe*

Answer (score 1):

I had a lot of problems with this remote helper issue. I ensured that I had installed all the expat, curl etc. but finally resolved it by updating gcc after finding that version 4.4.4 was duff. Just did a yum update and recompiled with 4.4.6.

Answer (score 1):

On centos 7:

```
$ yum install curl-devel
$ yum reinstall git
```

That work´s for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you're experiencing issues with the GitHub CLI (gh) on Ubuntu20.04 and have installed it via Snap, try these steps:

1. Remove the Snap Version: Run `sudo snap remove gh` to uninstall it.
2. Reinstall Using Official Instructions: Follow the installation guide at GitHub CLI. The official site **advises against using the Snap version** - https://github.com/cli/cli/blob/trunk/docs/install_linux.md

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem today: git http broken after years of happy service. It seems caused by some Perl lib updates. Tried some sane suggestions on web, none worked. Had enough, I just removed all git stuff, got a new tarball from http://git-scm.com/, compiled and installed, and all things are back to normal. Give it try, or you can go dig deep into your logs...

Answer (score 0):

I had to add a couple of extra installs running CentOS release 5.10 (Final):

```
yum install openssl097a.x86_64 
yum install openssl-perl.x86_64
```

Using git-1.8.5:
    ./configure
    make clean
    make
    make install

```
git clone https://github.com/michaelficarra/CoffeeScriptRedux.git
Cloning into 'CoffeeScriptRedux'...
remote: Reusing existing pack: 4577, done.
remote: Counting objects: 24, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (23/23), done.
remote: Total 4601 (delta 13), reused 11 (delta 1)
Receiving objects: 100% (4601/4601), 2.60 MiB | 126.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (2654/2654), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
```

Answer (score 0):

I landed here once because I was working with git itself.  When I built it the default makefile installed the binary in ~/bin/git.  Since my PATH had ~/bin first when I ran 'git pull --rebase' it used the one in ~/bin and consequently could not locate the helpers.

I worked around the issue by running '/usr/bin/git ...' with a full path (alternatively I could have adjusted my PATH).

Answer (score 0):

worked

#### 1- I had to remove git:

```
sudo apt-get remove git
```

#### 2- re - install git with the -all suffix:

```
sudo apt-get install git-all
```

as taught here: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Installing-Git

#### 3- checked all settings (user name & email) of my github account

by the way I was mistaken the good email which was the source of my errors ;) 
    https://github.com/settings/profile  
check your username 
     https://github.com/settings/emails  
 
check your email is the good one

#### 4- I have followed the tutorial of git here

https://help.github.com/articles/connecting-to-github-with-ssh

Answer (score 0):

In my case nothing was successful, after a while looking what was happening I found this on my config file. Not sure how it got there

```
% cat ~/.gitconfig 
[user]
    email = xxxxxxx@gmail.com
    name = xxxxxx
[alias]
    g = grep -n -i --heading --break
[url "git+https://github.com/"]
    insteadOf = git@github.com:
[url "git+https://"]
    insteadOf = git://
```

After removing the url properties everything was working fine again

Answer (score 0):

CentOS Minimal usually install version 1.8 git by `yum install git`command.

The best way is to build & install it from source code. Current version is `2.18.0`.

1. Download the source code from `https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/`
   or `curl -o git-2.18.0.tar.gz https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/git-2.18.0.tar.gz`
2. Unzip by `tar -zxf git-2.18.0.tar.gz && cd git-2.18.0`
3. Install the dependency package by executing `yum install autoconf curl-devel expat-devel gettext-devel openssl-devel perl-devel zlib-devel asciidoc xmlto openjade perl* texinfo`
4. Install docbook2X, it's not in the rpm repository. Download and install by

   $ curl -o docbook2X-0.8.8-17.el7.x86_64.rpm http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/Packages/d/docbook2X-0.8.8-17.el7.x86_64.rpm
   $ rpm -Uvh docbook2X-0.8.8-17.el7.x86_64.rpm

And make a unix link name:

```
ln -s /usr/bin/db2x_docbook2texi /usr/bin/docbook2x-texi
```

5. Compile and install, reference to https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Installing-Git

   $ make configure
   $ ./configure --prefix=/usr
   $ make all doc info
   $ sudo make install install-doc install-html install-info
6. Reboot your server (If not, you may encounter `Unable to find remote helper for 'https'` error）

   $ reboot now
7. Test:

   $ git clone https://github.com/volnet/v-labs.git
   $ cd v-labs
   $ touch test.txt
   $ git add .
   $ git commit -m "test git install"
   $ git push -u

Answer (score 0):

I got this error on Windows while using TortoiseGit. Reinstalling Git for Windows and telling TortoiseGit the path to git.exe by re-running the First Start Wizard fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case `git --exec-path` was pointing to the correct path and `git-remote-https` existed but didn't have execution permission. So `chmod +x git-remote-http` fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

found this in 2020
and solution solved the issue with OMZ
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13018777/13222154

```sh
...
➜  ~ cd $ZSH
➜  .oh-my-zsh (master) ✗ git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh.git (push)
➜  .oh-my-zsh (master) ✗ date ; omz update
Wed Sep 30 16:16:31 CDT 2020
Updating Oh My Zsh
fatal: Unable to find remote helper for 'https'
There was an error updating. Try again later?
omz::update: restarting the zsh session...

...

    ln "$execdir/git-remote-http" "$execdir/$p" 2>/dev/null || \
    ln -s "git-remote-http" "$execdir/$p" 2>/dev/null || \
    cp "$execdir/git-remote-http" "$execdir/$p" || exit; \
done && \
./check_bindir "z$bindir" "z$execdir" "$bindir/git-add"
➜  git-2.9.5 
➜  git-2.9.5 
➜  git-2.9.5 
➜  git-2.9.5 omz update       
Updating Oh My Zsh
remote: Enumerating objects: 296, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (296/296), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (115/115), done.
remote: Total 221 (delta 146), reused 179 (delta 105), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (221/221), 42.89 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (146/146), completed with 52 local objects.
From https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
   7deda85..f776af2  master     -> origin/master
Created autostash: 273f6e9
```