# Getting fatal error while downloading android source code using Repo

Tags: git, android-source, repository

I want to download android source code.
I followed following steps,

```
$ curl https://dl-ssl.google.com/dl/googlesource/git-repo/repo > ~/bin/repo
$ chmod a+x ~/bin/repo
$ mkdir android-source
$ cd android-source
$ repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest
```

but getting error

```
**Get https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo
fatal: Unable to find remote helper for 'https'**
```

I am using Ubuntu-10.04 and I have installed required all the packages and followed all the step mentioned over [here](http://source.android.com/source/initializing.html)

Any help would be appreciated,

Thanks, Nirav

Comment: Make sure you have curl-devel installed

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8329485/git-clone-fatal-unable-to-find-remote-helper-for-https

Comment: Although you have curl, you didn't install libcurl-devel. Install it and try again.

Comment: Unable to install curl-devel & libcurl-devel. Getting error "Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Couldn't find package libcurl-devel"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't get curl to work, you can use

```
wget -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/dl/googlesource/git-repo/repo > ~/bin/repo
```

instead.

BTW, you can check if your curl version supports https by running

```
curl -V
```

which should print "https" somewhere if it does.

Comment: the link does not exist anymore.

Comment: The latest URL can be found at http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html ; the point of my answer being that you can use "wget -O -" instead of curl.