# Problems when cloning repo with GIt

Tags: macos, git, osx-mavericks

When I enter the command:

`git clone https://<repo_url>.git`

I get the following output:

`warning: templates not found /usr/share/git-core/templates`

`fatal: Unable to find remote helper for 'https'`

I read that it could have something to do with curl, but curl is already installed and in my PATH variable.
What could be causing this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The "Git Template" section [on this blog](http://nuclearsquid.com/writings/git-tricks-tips-workflows/) sounds like your problem.  Try running `git init` and then cloning from within that repo.  Alternatively....

Did you have curl installed when you installed Git?  You probably found this already seeing as you read about curl possibly being the issue - ["Unable to find remote helper for 'https'" during git clone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8329485/git-clone-fatal-unable-to-find-remote-helper-for-https)  This is saying that you should install curl and then rebuild git.  The rebuild git commands should work as is.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I already had curl before installing git, but I tried to reinstall it anyway. The problem persists. And after running `brew install curl` I get `make[1]: *** [libcurl_la-file.lo] Error 1`

Comment: Are you able to use the Git transport instead?
`git clone --recursive git://<repo_url>.get`

Possibly your curl version, be it one you installed or the one that came boxed with your OS, was not installed with https support.  But that would be really weird.

Comment: Didn't work either, I got "repository not found". I guess my environment variables became all messed up along with the tools installed after updating to Mavericks. I'll just do a fresh install of the SO and see if that solves all the issues I'm having. Until that I'll use SourceTree because it's working. Many thanks for taking your time.