# OpenWRT git clone fatal: Unable to find remote helper for 'http'

Tags: git, openwrt

I'm trying to install LINC-Switch to OpenWRT and stuck on following problem:

```
git clone https://github.com/FlowForwarding/LINC-Switch.git
```

and get an error:

```
git fatal: Unable to find remote helper for 'https'
```

According to this [link](https://forum.openwrt.org/viewtopic.php?id=35399) I've compiled git package without NO_CURL flag in Makefile. I even recompile dist trying to solve the problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [git clone: fatal: Unable to find remote helper for 'https'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8329485/git-clone-fatal-unable-to-find-remote-helper-for-https)

Comment: Did you tried this url too? git@github.com:FlowForwarding/LINC-Switch.git

Comment: I'm, but https://github.com/FlowForwarding/LINC-Switch/blob/master/rebar.config resolves dependencies via http

Answer (score 40):

Just use git-http instead.

```
opkg remove git
opkg install git-http
```

Comment: Cannot install git-http

Comment: Silly me for thinking `opkg install git` would install `git`!

Answer (score 5):

Next to using `git-http`, as Nemo Alex suggests, you should also have the `ca-bundle` installed:

```
opkg update
opkg remove git
opkg install git-http
opkg install ca-bundle
```