# OpenWRT + https + git

Tags: git, curl, openwrt, opkg

I've got a TP-Link MR3020 router flashed with OpenWRT 12.09, r36088 installed on it. I am trying to clone a git repository via HTTPS but get the following error:

```
fatal: Unable to find remote helper for 'https'
```

Here is a similar problem but it was solved for CentOS.

["Unable to find remote helper for 'https'" during git clone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8329485/git-clone-fatal-unable-to-find-remote-helper-for-https)

Following its advice, I made sure that curl is installed. However, I can't find any opkg packages for curl-devel and there doesn't seem to be any that I can manually download http://curl.haxx.se/dlwiz/?type=devel&os=Linux.

I also found this question ([OpenWRT git clone fatal: Unable to find remote helper for 'http'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22506989/openwrt-git-clone-fatal-unable-to-find-remote-helper-for-http?rq=1)) which is the exact question I have, but the git-http repository doesn't seem to exist for opkg.

Comment: Installing `git-http` worked for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A lot of the times since routers are *very* limited in storage space, many of the applications in the repos are just the bare bones of that application with many of the features turned off to minimize space consumption.

Git is no different. The git binary in the opkg repo was compiled without https support.

To fix this, you are probably going to need to cross-compile your own version of git with both curl and expat enabled... which is fun and exciting. (if interested check out http://buildroot.uclibc.org/ I use mips-buildroot-linux-uclibc as my cross compiler for my TP-Link WDR 3500)

An alternative would be to try to use a different protocol (either ssh or git) if practical. Those protocols are better supported by git anyhow.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes, the space limitation gets in my way so I mount a 16GB flash drive on it. I ultimately ended up using SSH. It works, but it's annoying because I have to whitelist each key on bitbucket which isn't as scalable as I'd like. (I'm deploying a bunch of routers out to remote client locations)

Comment: If you used ssh agent forwarding, you would only need to whitelist the key of your machine.
You should be able to do this even with multiple chained connection ;)

Answer (score 0):

Installing the ca-bundle package fixed it:

opkg install ca-bundle