# The certificate /usr/share/rhn/RHNS-CA-CERT is expired

Tags: git, yum

After installing git i was getting the below error:
git clone: fatal: Unable to find remote helper for 'https'

I followed the link : 
["Unable to find remote helper for 'https'" during git clone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8329485/git-clone-fatal-unable-to-find-remote-helper-for-https)

and tried the below:

```
$ yum install curl-devel
$ # cd to wherever the source for git is
$ cd /usr/local/src/git-1.7.9  
$ ./configure
$ make
$ make install
```

I am getting the below error:
The certificate /usr/share/rhn/RHNS-CA-CERT is expired.

Thoughts??

Answer (score 3):

Your SSL certificate sesms to have expired. Replace it with a valid one.

```
rm /usr/share/rhn/RHNS-CA-CERT
wget -P /usr/share/rhn http://f.cl.ly/items/1B19031O2E0m1k3E2n3u/RHNS-CA-CERT
```

Also, Update the Red Hat Network packages

```
yum -y update rhn*
```

Comment: also https://access.redhat.com/solutions/353033 and http://osdir.com/ml/spacewalk-list/2014-11/msg00038.html

Answer (score 2):

This can also happen on Oracle Linux, in which case you can simply bypass the ULN/RHN yum plugins and grab the latest **rhn-client-tools** from a public repo.

```
yum update rhn-client-tools --noplugins
```