# Git: Unable to find remote helper for 'ssh'

Tags: git, ssh

Whenever I try to push to a remote repository via SSH I keep getting the following error message: fatal: Unable to find remote helper for 'ssh'.

Using:

1. Cygwin 2.5.0
2. Git 2.8.1
3. Windows 7 64 Bit
4. ssh-pageant

The thing is that I had the exactly same approach working quite a while ago on one of the projects and now decided to try using it for another.

OpenSSL, Git and Curl are all in place.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to SO! more information on what exact command were you using and also details about if this repo that you are trying to push is yours or you cloned from someone in github might help us diagnose the issue..

Comment: OpenSSL is not OpenSSH. You need to have something that handles ssh.

Are you using something like SourceTree? It's installer adds all needed dependencies.

Comment: @Mir I've got OpenSSH along with Cygwin, as I said previously - no changes were made and the same setup was working before. I've tested SSH bridge with the server and it works perfectly fine.

Comment: @uDaY No, everything's set up in test environment. I have created a blank bare repo on the server and trying to push the master branch of a project on local machine to it. 

Just tried runing git remote show against the remote repo and that one produced the same error, however when added -n option it worked. Any ideas?

Comment: Is it "SSH" or "ssh"?  Case matters.

Comment: @KeithThompson SSH

Comment: "ssh" is correct. Did you specify "SSH" somewhere?

Comment: @KeithThompson Yes and it all works, I can ssh to the server using RSA token. It looks to me like there's an issue with git rather than SSH itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same error message. I guess I had a malformed `ssh` url in the `git` command.

I removed `ssh` part `ssh:://`, changed host name (taken from `~/.ssh/config`) to IP address, and that worked.

Comment: I agree about the malformed ssh url... try 'ssh://' instead of 'ssh:://' (note the double-colon)

Answer (score 1):

Decided to give this approach another try and it worked. Seemed to be some sort of an issue with curl.

["Unable to find remote helper for 'https'" during git clone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8329485/git-clone-fatal-unable-to-find-remote-helper-for-https)

Thanks anyway!