# Bonobo Git Server - can’t do git clone from cmd - Visual studio 2015 can

Tags: git, jenkins, cmd, bonobo

I am trying to set up continuous deployment on windows using **Bonobo** git server and **Jenkins**.

The Bonobo server is running fine on machine X. Form machine Y I can use my NuGets.git repository (on X) from Visual studio 2015 to do git clone, push, changes, sync…

But when I tried to set up Jenkins to do git clone using the Git Plugin it fails. So I thought I would try to make git clone from a command prompt on machine X - but it also failed (with the git that was included in the Bonobo server)

**I tried the following commands**

***Gets the same error***
**git clone http://masterserver/Bonobo.Git.Server/NuGets.git 

git clone http://admin@masterserver/Bonobo.Git.Server/NuGets.git**

Cloning into 'NuGets'...
*warning: templates not found /share/git-core/templates

**fatal: Unable to find remote helper for 'http'***

**git clone git://masterserver/Bonobo.Git.Server/NuGets.git** 
Cloning into 'NuGets'... 
warning: templates not found /share/git-core/templates 
***fatal: unable to connect to masterserver: 

masterserver[0: fe80::eddd:307e:2856:4c3f%11]: errno=No error 

masterserver[1: 192.168.1.28]: errno=No error***

**git clone git://admin@masterserver/Bonobo.Git.Server/NuGets.git** 
Cloning into 'NuGets'... 
warning: templates not found /share/git-core/templates  
***fatal: Unable to look up admin@masterserver (port 9418) (A non-recoverable error occurred during a database lookup. )***

I am quite lost her - any help and hints are very welcome

Comment: This is a client problem, not a Bonobo problem.  You should install a proper version of Git on your client machine and then try again, with the URL which Bonobo gives you in the repo admin page (which will be an http or https URL, not a git:// one.)

Comment: Yes - I added a proper version of Git - That worked Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since Bonobo is hosted inside IIS it only supports HTTP/S protocols as listed in [FAQ](https://bonobogitserver.com/frequently-asked-questions/), therefore only your first attempt is valid.

As for the `Unable to find remote helper for 'http'` simple search yields [the following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13018777/7034621).

Comment: If it is cUrl you refer to, then it is installed on machine X (windows) via the env.-var path right?

Comment: Perhaps you should install [Git for Windows](https://git-scm.com/download/win) as your CI server appears to use some custom build?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Repository -> Edit the repository you are trying to clone and then give the user either contributor or administrator rights.