# fatal unable to find remote helper for https

Tags: linux, git, github, vim, redhat

When **trying to clone a repo with git** on a Red Hat Enterprise **Linux** server:

```
git clone https://github.com/user/repo.git
```

I receive an error with output:

> fatal: Unable to find remote helper for 'https'

I noticed the error when trying to install packages with **Vundle** for **vim**. When I looked at the log i found that it was git that was causing the error. The problem is not present when separately running:

```
sudo git clone https://github.com/user/repo.git
```

... and running:

```
/usr/bin/git clone https://github.com/user/repo.git
```

... also worked fine. Since I run git through vim in this case **I want it to work with just the `git` command**.

I have tried to uninstall all the yum-installed git-related packages. I have also tried the approach in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8329485/unable-to-find-remote-helper-for-https-during-git-clone) Stackoverflow answer without any results. I have tried to install the latest git from source with [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-git-on-centos-7) tutorial.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Unable to find remote helper for 'https'" during git clone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8329485/unable-to-find-remote-helper-for-https-during-git-clone)

Answer (score 0):

After 2/3 of a work day trying to figure out what was wrong i manually removed every git-related file and directory i could find. Then i simply reinstalled git with

```
sudo yum install git
```

Now is everything working fine.

So try doing

```
find /usr/ -name 'git*' -type d
```

to find the git-related directories, then remove all these directories. After this you do a new search and pipe that into less to handle the possible large output,

```
find /usr/ -name 'git*' | less
```

take note of the exec files and remove them. Mine where in /usr/local/bin. After this you reinstall git with yum like above.