# Build Failed in Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, bitbucket

status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: fatal: Unable to find remote helper for 'https'

How do I fix the above..?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the Jenkins agent OS on which the Jenkins job executes itself.

On Linux, that message typically means, [as in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13018777/6309), that (lib)curl-devel is not installed.