# FreeBSD having trouble pushing to GitHub

Tags: git, curl, github, freebsd

I am running FreeBSD 9.2.1. I have tried pushing to GitHub via:

```
sudo git push -u origin master
```

But I get:

> fatal: Unable to find remote helper for 'https'

I have tried updating git to 2.17.0 and also getting a later version of curl and recompiling git. But to no avail.

What may I do about this?

Comment: Why are you using `sudo` to do a git push? That shouldn't be necessary. I have a hunch that if you fix the problem that is causing you to use `sudo`, that will fix this problem.

Comment: Sudo is just a bad habit. Same result w/o sudo

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Unable to find remote helper for 'https'" during git clone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8329485/unable-to-find-remote-helper-for-https-during-git-clone)

Comment: The solutions there are only given for ubuntu not freebsd

Comment: But they're both Unix-like operating systems.

Comment: I can’t implement the libcurl solution because it’s freebsd. I can only install curl

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170456/discussion-between-robin-green-and-ariel-baron).

Answer (score 0):

`cd /usr/ports/devel/git`
`make config`

select checkbox "**Data transfer support via cURL**"

rebuild and reinstall git:
`make deinstall`
`make install clean`

It's checked on FreeBSD 12