# GitHub clone issue in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, github, https, clone

How to solve this error
fatal: unable to find remote helper for 'https'
while cloning to Github

The command I used was: github clone "https:/.....link"
I have tried different solutions but no gain.

Comment: Assuming you mean the git command, check the first answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean : `git clone` instead of `github clone` ?

You can check related issue : ["Unable to find remote helper for 'https'" during git clone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8329485/unable-to-find-remote-helper-for-https-during-git-clone)

Comment: Oh, mistake!
git clone