# fatal: unable to find remote helper for 'https' : problem when git pull or push

Tags: git, version-control, gitlab

I am pretty new to git and today an issue appeared when trying to push or pull to/from a git repository. My git version on CentOs7 is 2.27.0 and the error appears as:

```
git push origin master
fatal: unable to find remote helper for 'https'
```

When checking the configuration:

```
git config --list --show-origin
file:/users/iess/.gitconfig     user.name=alberto.iess
file:/users/iess/.gitconfig     filter.lfs.clean=git-lfs clean -- %f
file:/users/iess/.gitconfig     filter.lfs.smudge=git-lfs smudge -- %f
file:/users/iess/.gitconfig     filter.lfs.process=git-lfs filter-process
file:/users/iess/.gitconfig     filter.lfs.required=true
file:/users/iess/.gitconfig     url.https://.insteadof=git+https://
file:.git/config        core.repositoryformatversion=0
file:.git/config        core.filemode=true
file:.git/config        core.bare=false
file:.git/config        core.logallrefupdates=true
file:.git/config        remote.origin.url=https://gitlab.com/astrogwml/ccsn-lstm.git
file:.git/config        remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
file:.git/config        branch.master.remote=origin
file:.git/config        branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
```

https://gitlab.com/astrogwml/ccsn-lstm.git is the exact string I get on the gitlab repository for Clone with HTTPS. I really don't know where to start to tackle this problem. Help (and references) would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does anything here https://stackoverflow.com/q/8329485/7976758 help? Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+fatal%3A+unable+to+find+remote+helper+for+https

Comment: I solved generating a new ssh key and modifying the .git/config file to allow ssh pull and push. Up to now I'm still not sure what happened, neither how to solve it with https