# Github CLI - Unable to find remote helper for 'https'

Tags: github, github-cli

Github CLI is throwing the following error when I try to make a PR from the command line.

```
fatal: Unable to find remote helper for 'https'
exit status 128
```

I've tried the steps on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8329485/unable-to-find-remote-helper-for-https-during-git-clone) and `git clone` works fine for me. I'm also able to see the status of PRs by using `gh pr status`

Does anyone have any ideas why this might be happening?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This is all set. After installing the library, I just needed to reboot my machine.

Answer (score 0):

Has the same issue with the `snap` version of the tool (`1.30`).
Switching over to the prebuilt binary of version `1.35` fixed this issue for me.